# Python is cutting of a part of mails from gmail

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

This code print emails from gmail, but when i print 'body' shows only a part of mail.
I've founded that there is more or less 200 chars in output,
so probably message is too large to be a string, but I don't know how to solve it.
Maybe hould i save these mails to diffrend type.

```
results2 = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
messageids = results2.get('messages', [])
for messageids in messageids:

    message =(service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id=messageids['id']).execute())
    body = message['snippet']
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you look at [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages), it says that 'snippet' is "A short part of the message text." You probably want to look in the 'payload' parts.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this thread: [Python imaplib fetch body emails gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029768/python-imaplib-fetch-body-emails-gmail), you can get the contents of the body by doing any of the following:

> ```
> msg.as_string()
> str(msg)
> repr(msg)
> ```
>
> Source: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message

You may also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239777/get-all-the-mail-with-body-using-imap-in-python) for additional reference.